# Laravel + Tailwindcss 1.8.7: How to Install

Tags: laravel

I had no problem before when installing old versions of tailwindcss. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help. This is what I did so far but it does not work:

1. via npm

```php
npm install tailwindcss
```

2. resources/sass/app.scss

```php
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

3. Create Tailwind config file

```php
npx tailwindcss init
```

4. webpack.mix.js

```php
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');

const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [ tailwindcss('tailwind.config.js') ],
    });
```

i.e. welcome.php

```php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="bg-purple 400"> //Does not work

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O. ok. apologies. will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to implement tailwindcss in laravel you need to

-1 install Tailwind via npm

```
npm install tailwindcss
```

-2 import style in app.scss

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

-3 create tailwindcss config file

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

-4 add this code inside your tailwind.config.js

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
    purge: [

        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/**/*.vue',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    variants: {
        opacity: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus', 'disabled'],
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/ui')],
};
```

-5 install tailwindcss ui

```
npm install @tailwindcss/ui
```

-6 finally compile your code

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution:

`https://medium.com/@larapeak/setup-tailwindcss-in-laravel-7-x-94d78ebc9109`

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
      processCssUrls: false,
      postCss: [ tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js') ],
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `webpack.mix.js` file should look something like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.scss', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);
```

and your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
    purge: [
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    variants: {
        opacity: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus', 'disabled'],
    },
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed your instructions but it still does not work.